# PHP Transaction confirm with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to confirm transaction from other third-party, e.g I pay goods of $50 to juma Joe after click pay button and pay page is still loading and tell me to wait almost 5 seconds to check if the transaction is processing succeed, and if the transaction succeeds, it redirects to a success page.

So i need javascript and html confirmation code call from php to check if transaction is success then to show redirect seconds.

Thank you

Bellow is code for for validate transaction

```
$result = array();
$url = 'https://api.xxxx.co/transaction/verify/reference';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt(
$ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx']
);
$request = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch)){
echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

if ($request) {
 $result = json_decode($request, true);
}

if (array_key_exists('data', $result) && array_key_exists('status',             $result['data']) && ($result['data']['status'] === 'success')) {
echo "Transaction was successful";
//Compete transaction
}else{
// Not complete
echo "Transaction not complete";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. You can using ajax to request and response in you code.

Example:
PHP Code: validate.php

```
//....above you code here
// my code config response
$res = [
         'mess' => null,
         'status' => 404
       ];

//...you code validation result
if (array_key_exists('data', $result) && array_key_exists('status', $result['data']) && ($result['data']['status'] === 'success')) {
    //Compete transaction
    $res['mess'] = "Transaction was successful";
    $res['status'] = 200;
}else{
    // Not complete
    $res['mess'] = "Transaction not complete";
    $res['status'] = 404;
}
// my code response mess
echo json_encode($res);
```

So, below my front-end code, using jQuery Ajax to send POST request.

[Document you can check here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  function validate(){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'validate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                console.log("you code here for success");
            } else {
                console.log("you code here for fail");
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("Request is error with: " + err);
        }
     });
  }
});
```

HTML for submit button. Call to javascript

`<button id="submit" type="submit" onclick="validate();">Send Request</button>`

Comment: Your code is work well but i don't need to click submit button, i need to check respond every 5seconds then if success, it redirect to other site.

Comment: @T.G.B you can using setInterval(function validate(){}, 5000); to do this

Comment: Okay, congrats, you can upvote my comment, it's happyfull :')

Answer (score 0):

```
function checking(){
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: status.php,
      success: function(data){
          if (data.done=='y') window.location = 'done.html';
      }
    });
}


setInterval(checking,5000);
```

With this script, you can call for every 5 seconds. But the best practice is to use a webhook. For more information, search it up on your payment gateway API documentation.

**status.php**

```
  $result = array();
$respond=array();
    $url = 'https://api.xxxx.co/transaction/verify/reference';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt(
    $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx']
    );
    $request = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)){
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($request) {
     $result = json_decode($request, true);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('data', $result) && array_key_exists('status',             $result['data']) && ($result['data']['status'] === 'success')) {
$respond[done]='y';
    //Compete transaction
    }else{
    // Not complete
$respond[done]='n';
}

echo json_encode($respond);
```

Comment: I have understand well now, and i have get some knowledge.